# Can't run UIAutomationTest from command line

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, ui-automation

I have an iOS application, and I want to put it in continuous integration. The strategy I'm using to do that is trying to run the tests from the command line.

I'm trying to do it using the following script:

```
TRACETEMPLATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate"
instruments   -t $TRACETEMPLATE build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app -e UIACSCRIPT "UnitTests/SomeTest.js"
```

SomeTest.js is a simple javascript file that I can run in Instrumentation inside Xcode and it works. I build my application using:

```
xcodebuild -alltargets -sdk iphonesimulator5.1
```

and this generates the MyApp.app. I can run the application from Xcode in the simulator just fine, however, when I try to run by the instruments, I get a box saying that there is an unknown error and in the command line it prints:

```
2012-05-15 15:32:59.928 instruments[17548:1d03] Recording cancelled : At least one target failed to launch; aborting run
Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
```

Can anyone give me any help/suggestions about what might be happening and how can I fix this?

Also, it always open the iPad simulator? Can I make it that it opens any simulator I want?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and also can't resolve it :(

Comment: I couldn't find a solution so far. I'll try asking on apple own forums to see if they come up with something. If I find out something, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was getting this same error and nearly pulled my hair out trying to solve it.  The error messages are completely unhelpful.

What ended up being the problem for me was the .app file that I was pointing to.  Once I found the "right" .app file that was deeply buried in the 5.1 Simulator folder, I was able to finally run UIAutomation tests from the command line with Xcode 4.3.

The path to the .app that worked for me:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/{string-of-numbers-and-letters}/MyApp.app/
```

Here is the full command I'm using to run UIAutomation tests from the command line with Xcode 4.3:

```
instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/{string-of-numbers-and-letters}/MyApp.app/ -e UIASCRIPT /Path/To/TestFile.js
```

Hope this helps someone else, as the documentation out there for this is extremely lacking.

**Update**

Note that as of Xcode 4.5.2, the automation template location has changed from that on my original answer:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I don't know if I can put this in a ci server though (don't think my Makefile will update the app there, I'll test later and see if it works....)

Comment: Hey @spotdog13, I am getting this error when I run it - `Fail: The target application appears to have died
Instruments Trace Complete`

Comment: @Legolas, that sounds to me like the version of the .app you are pointing to isn't the most recent version of your app.  Have you made sure there aren't multiple folders at ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/{string-of-numbers-and-letters} ??  If there is more than one "{string-of-numbers-and-letters}" folder in reference to the above path, try another one and see if it works.  My guess is that you're trying to run an older version of your app.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: If you "reset content and settings" on the simulator, does the path to the .app still work?

Comment: @Ian - I'm not sure, but you can easily open a terminal and cd to the path to see if it's still valid or if it has changed.

Comment: I had done that before I asked -- resetting the simulator seems to delete the app directory on my machine, so I was curious whether it was the same on yours.  This is a concern because it means you won't know the app path before starting instruments (which normally installs the app onto the simulator for you, from its build location).

Comment: Well...I imagine you could find a way to wildcard the path.

Answer (score 6):

The correct location of the Automation.tracetemplate, as of Xcode 4.5.2, is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate`

Comment: I wish I could give you 10 up votes. Why do they keep changing it?

Answer (score 1):

The paths for the command line invocation of UIAutomation has changed slightly over the past couple of years. I have written a few bash shell scripts that work together which can launch your UIAutomation test file in a way that works with Xcode 4.4.1.

See this gist: https://gist.github.com/3605692#comments

In a nutshell, the key command ends up being:

`instruments -t $INSTRUMENTS_TEMPLATE $APP_PATH -e UIASCRIPT $SCRIPT_PATH -e UIARESULTSPATH $RESULTS_PATH`

My scripts show the variable substitutions needed. The other benefit is that iOS simulator apps have often changing GUID as part of their path. My script will find them, so you don't have to hard code the temporary GUID in your builds / scripts / command line invocations.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my english is very bad.
As the easiest way to run this script from Teamtsity? Each assembly - the numbers and letters are different.
Not the easiest way:

1. clean the simulator prior to assembly
2. find the folder with the program, and it contains these numbers and letters, written in the variable.
3. This variable, such as writing the script.

Maybe there's a way easier to take from these numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The Build Configuration should be debug than Release. That was the reason for the error in my case.
 You can change Build Configuration in 'Edit Schemes' and by choosing the Profile tab. Verify that build tab also is in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I did the `ps` command to see which processes are running.  I found that instruments was still running.  I then did `killall instruments` and that killed the instruments process.  I then did my instruments command and it worked perfect after that.